# NTP doesn't sync time and ntpq displays offset very high

Tags: linux, ntp

I am using linux angstrom. I installed the package ntp. I changed my system time by 1 second to check whether ntp syncs my system time or not. But it doesn't sync the time. I ran ntpq -pn command to check the status an dit displays the offset to be 43449(around this value). This must be in milliseconds. How can a time difference of just 1 second make the offset so large?
This is my ntp.conf file:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
logfile   /var/log/ntp.log
statistics clockstats
statsdir /var/log/ntp.stats

server 128.138.140.44 minpoll 6 maxpoll 10
server 0.ubuntu.pool.ntp.org
server 127.127.1.0
fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 14
# Defining a default security setting
restrict default
```

Also after once setting the time using ntpdate, when I again changed the time by 1 sec, then ntpq -pn displays everything(offset, delay, jitter) to be zero.
My log file output is something like this:
    20 Oct 04:45:09 ntpd[925]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
    20 Oct 04:45:09 ntpd[925]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
    20 Oct 04:45:09 ntpd[925]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
    20 Oct 04:45:09 ntpd[925]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 10.20.55.121:123
    20 Oct 04:45:09 ntpd[925]: Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123
    20 Oct 04:45:09 ntpd[925]: Listen normally on 5 eth0        [fe80::214:2dff:fe2b:53a8%2]:123 
    20 Oct 04:45:09 ntpd[925]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
    20 Oct 04:45:58 ntpd[925]: ntpd exiting on signal 15 (Terminated)
    20 Oct 04:45:58 ntpd[925]: 128.138.140.44 local addr 10.20.55.121 -> 
    20 Oct 04:45:58 ntpd[925]: 127.127.1.0 local addr 127.0.0.1 -> 
    20 Oct 04:45:58 ntpd[925]: 125.62.193.121 local addr 10.20.55.121 ->

Please help how to configure ntp to make it run smoothly without any problem.

Comment: I would like to focus on the line "ntpd exiting on signal 15" in my log file. I have no idea what the signal 15 means and why did ntp exit. Please help.

Comment: can you please endit your question to include the output from `ntpq -pcrv`

Comment: signal 15 is `SIGTERM` as in something stopped the process.